# "add ignored tag" feature doesn't work at the search page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, search

I have encountered a problem when editing tags on the search results page:

1. go https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0
2. add ignored tag at the right-side tool-bar
3. refresh the page
4. the tag disappears (!)

So, I've lost all the tags I've added while searching ...

My web-browser is Opera-11.

Comment: Reproed on Safari 5.0.3 (6533.19.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug found and destroyed - this will go out with the next build.